# Problem populating object with JSON data?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Code:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
// @JsonPropertyOrder({ "id","matricula" ,"dv", "nome" })
public class UsuarioDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("matricula")
    private String matricula;
    @JsonProperty("dv")
    private String dv;
    @JsonProperty("nome")
    private String nome;

    @Service
    public class UsuarioService {
        public UsuarioDTO consultausuario() {
            return new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:3000/usuario/", UsuarioDTO.class).getBody();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 2, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.pdv.api.dto.UsuarioDTO["id"])
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide a [mre].

Comment: Where is your JSON? You need to include it in your question

Comment: Your JSON does not match your Object. The Id is an Object in your JSON while being just a String in your Java-Class. Without your JSON all I can say is you need to create a fitting ID-Class and use that as the type for id.

Answer (score 0):

My solution  was removed @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY) and  @JsonProperty and  after  modified this method.

@Autowired
//private ModelMapper modelMapper;
public  UsuarioDTO consultausuario(String id) throws JsonProcessingException {

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String  url = "http://localhost:3000/usuario" + id  ;

    // return  new mo().getForObject("http://localhost:3000/usuario",UsuarioDTO.class);

    return restTemplate.getForObject(url,UsuarioDTO.class);
}
```

Thanks!